# Do Azure SQL Databases in a Elastic Pool use the pool's storage?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-elasticpool

Saw the below specs about Azure SQL Database in Elastic Pool, could someone please explain why a pool with 500 GB storage limitation could hold 100 databases and each database could go up to 1 TB storage if the databases need to use pool's storage to hold them?

Or the databases actually not take up the pool storage? If that's the case, what the pool's storage is used for?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The limit of 1 TB per database is independent of the limit of storage per pool. 1 TB per database is the limit for all the available service tiers (50, 100, 200) on Standard Edition. I have set the maximum size on an elastic pool to 2 TB in the past, in that case a database reaching 1 TB is possible but with the service tiers you shared with us that is not possible.

The sum of size of all databases must be below de maximum storage per pool. Databases use that storage.

Comment: so for the 50 eDTUs per pool tier, the maximum storage per pool is 500 GB, if that pool only had one database, the maximum size of that database would only be 500 GB? If the pool got two databases, the sum of size of the two databases can only be 500 GB in maximum?